# Divide excel column to N equal groups

Tags: excel

I have a column with ordinal values. I want to have another column that ranks them in equal groups (relatively to their value).

Example: If I have a score and I want to divide to 5 equal groups:

Score
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10

What function do I use in the new column to get this eventually:

Score   Group
100          5
90         5
80         4
70         4
60         3
50         3
40         2
30         2
20         1
10         1

Thanks! (I'm guessing the solution is somewhere in mod, row and count - but I couldn't find any good solution for this specific problem)

Comment: How do you want to handle those cases where it isn't evenly divisible? (e.g. if you have 11 data points but want to divide into 5 groups. 11 isn't divisible by 5).

Comment: Basically I don't mind, but for the sake of generalizing - let them go into the last group. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about how the groups are split for groups that aren't evenly divisible, you can use this formula and drag down as far as necessary:

```
= FLOOR(5*(COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,ROW())))/COUNTA(A:A),1)+1
```

Possibly a more efficient solution exists, but this is the first way I thought to do it.

Obviously you'll have to change the references to the `A` column if you want it in a different column.

See below for working example.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! More complicated than I thought. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Just looks complicated, all it is doing is: `5*(<size of data>-<current data index>)/<size of data>` and then rounding that up to a whole number, unless the result is exactly a whole number, in that case it adds 1.